# Multiple WorkerRole service instances listening on different TCP input endpoint in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a Cloud Service with a Worker role configured.  The worker role basically listens on a port and performs actions as required.   What I want to be able to do is configure that worker role to have multiple instances running but to have each instance configured to listen on a different port (input endpoint).

Is this possible in Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Having each worker instance doing something different is against-the-grain for what cloud services are designed for. That is: It's designed for stateless scale-out: Each instance doing the same thing, but being able to scale for more traffic/capacity/cpu/whatever. In your case, that would mean having each worker instance listening in on all ports for all possible incoming traffic, and processing all traffic that comes in.

That said: You can configure an `InstanceInputEndpoint` to forward port-specific traffic to specific worker instances. The schema detail for configuring `InstanceInputEndpoint` is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557552.aspx). You might still need some decision-making logic in your worker instances, to determine what work it should be doing (and how you do this is specific to your app). And if you need to determine, inside an instance, the instance ID, you'd need to look at `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id` (assuming the Id doesn't change over time).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess my instances are doing the same thing as the code is exactly the same between them.  They are just doing it with data coming in from a different port.